# How to trigger a var after x actions

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. I want to trigger the action in function `activityDetected(eventName)` only after 100 click. How to do this ?

I know I have to put `let a = 1; ++a` but not sure where...

https://pastebin.com/SMsJsikE

```js
const intervalTimeout = 2000;

//here is where code should be added. let a = 1; ++a...
function activityDetected(eventName) {
    console.log(`Activity detected with the event name: ${eventName}!`);
    clearInterval(activityTimeout);
    activityTimeout = setInterval(recordNoActivity, intervalTimeout);
}

document.addEventListener('click', _ => {
    activityDetected('click');
});
```

Comment: Why not declare the counter outside the function? https://pastebin.com/Rk5M49Tt

Comment: Also u need to store counter inside cookies  or DB for maintaining count sequence. Once your page is reload it set your counter zero and again start.

Comment: Should that counter be persistent? what happens after 100 clicks? does the check restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare a counter outside the function and up it by 1 when the `eventName` is `'click'`. After that check for `a % 100` and put whatever action you want to call every 100 clicks in there.

Look at the code example:

```js
// For ease, change this to a smaller value to detect more often, higher to detect less often!
    const intervalTimeout = 2000;
    let a = 0;
     
    // Here's our interval, setting up the initial capture of no activity
    let activityTimeout = setInterval(recordNoActivity, intervalTimeout);
     
    // A single function to handle the events we're listening to.
    // clears the interval and restarts it, also tells us which event has cleared the interval!
    //here is where code should be added. let a = 1; ++a...
    function activityDetected(eventName) {
        if(eventName == 'click'){
            a++;
            if(a%100 == 0){
                // Trigger whatever you want to trigger after every 100 clicks
            }
        }
        console.log(`Activity detected with the event name: ${eventName}!`);
        clearInterval(activityTimeout);
        activityTimeout = setInterval(recordNoActivity, intervalTimeout);
    }
     
    // Set listening events
    document.addEventListener('keydown', _ => {
        activityDetected('keydown');
    });
     
    document.addEventListener('click', _ => {
        activityDetected('click');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation, it's working

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed by others on this thread the variable `a` should be declared and defined outside the function but the reason why this approach would work is because of [Closure](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-closures-simplified-d0d23fa06ba4?gi=324dfd192d5a)

So when the function is getting invoked an `execution context` is created which contains

1. scopeChain - it contains variableObject + all parent execution context's variableObject
2. variableObject - it contains function arguments / parameters, inner variable and function declarations
3. this - the this context.

Thus the variable `a` values would be saved before invoking the function and the variable will keep incrementing.